# cx_Oracle on 10g Client 32 Bit Unable to Acquire Environmental handle

Tags: oracle10g, python-2.x, cx-oracle

I am currently trying to set up a python script that connects to an Oracle DB to get Order Positions and calculcate certain KPIs and write them into a dedicated table.

However, as soon as I am trying to connect, Python throws

> "Interface Error: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle"

Yet, it does indeed work if I open the Toad for Oracle and connect to the DB prior to executing the python script.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle as oracle  
import sqlalchemy
import os

def main():
    ### See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797894/named-parameters-in-sql-queries-cx-oracle-ora-01460-unimplemented-or-unreas
    os.environ.update([('NLS_LANG', '.UTF8'),('ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE', 'TRUE'),])

    engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://USR:PW@IP/SID')
    sql_seasons = read_sql_file("Query.sql")
    table = pd.read_sql(sql_seasons, engine)
    ...
```

I have to work with an Oracle Client 10g (10.2) 32 Bit (Server-side: 12.1 64 Bit Version)

so I am using cx_Oracle-5.1.2-10g.win32-py2.7 5.1 (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-oracle/files/5.1.2/)

with Python 2.7 32 Bit (CPython)

Environmental Variables:

```
PATH = c:\oracle\products\10.2.0\bin
ORACLE_HOME = c:\oracle\products\10.2.0
TNS_ADMIN = c:\oracle\network
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\lib
```

oci.dll can be found c:\oracle\products\10.2.0\bin

The exact same happens when I try to connect by cx_Oracle directly instead of utilizing sqlalchemy
Is there a way to solve this problem? Are there any other oracle connectors for python that reliably allow me to access via a 10g client?
I've seen that there is also the zxJDBC connector that works with Jython. I'd like to avoid migrating to the java platform.

edit: 
Stack Trace down beneath:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\...\File.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\...\File.py", line 30, in main
    table = pd.read_sql(sql_seasons, engine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 416, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1092, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 983, in execute
    return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2063, in execute
    connection = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2112, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2151, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1465, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2147, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 387, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 766, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 516, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1138, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1135, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 333, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 651, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 105, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\oracle\cx_oracle.py", line 794, in connect
    *cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 393, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (cx_Oracle.InterfaceError) Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
```

Comment: It looks like `USR:PW` should be `USR/PW`, and `@IP/SID` should be `@IP/service_name`, and I'd include the port number too even if it's the default, so `@IP:1521/service_name`. The SID and service name *might* be the same but they often aren't.

Comment: based on sqlalchemy's documentation for oracle DBs it should be 

> create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pass@host:port/dbname[?key=value&key=value...]')

[link]http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.cx_oracle

Comment: OK, but for 'dbname' are you using the SID or the service name - they might not be the same, and JDBC URLs either end `:SID` or `/service_name`. And Toad might be using a TNS alias, in which case tnsnames.ora should show the real value to use.

Comment: I am indeed using the "database name" which, I presume, corresponds to the SID. 
I was also trying to fill in the service name via "...@IP:1521/?service_name=service_name". It still does not work.

Comment: Note, that connecting to the DB only works when Toad was opened and the connection string has this form: 
"oracle+cx_oracle://user:pw@IP:port/db_name"
any other connection string so far has failed with Toad being open.

Comment: Ok, I somehow got access to the 12c Oracle Client and now it works without any problems and even in python 3.6 with cx_oracle 6